# How to make transition go from 2s width to 2s height with a 50% increase height after button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem with my code is that I cannot have a 2s height transition like i'm normally suppose to after clicking the "changer l'animation" button. At first, there's a 2s width transition and when I click the "changer l'animation" I should have a 2s height transition on the logo and the logo should be increasing his height by 50%. 
Help me please. Hope I was quite understandable.
Thank you

```js
function genererpage() {

  //Image dans le header 
  var logo = document.createElement("img");
  logo.setAttribute("src", "Images/logo_js.jpg");
  logo.setAttribute("width", "175");
  logo.setAttribute("height", "110");
  logo.setAttribute("alt", "Logo de JavaScript");
  var header = document.createElement("header");
  header.appendChild(logo);
  document.body.appendChild(header);


  //Navigateur avec la liste et les liens
  var navigateur = document.createElement("nav");
  var listeSansOrdre = document.createElement("ul");
  var liste1 = document.createElement("li");
  var liste2 = document.createElement("li");
  var liste3 = document.createElement("li");
  var lien1 = document.createElement("a");
  var lien2 = document.createElement("a");
  var lien3 = document.createElement("a");
  var href = document.createAttribute("href");

  lien1.href = "#";
  lien2.href = "#";
  lien3.href = "#";

  var options = ["Accueil", "Nous joindre", "A propos de nous"]
  listeSansOrdre.id = "liste";

  lien1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options[0]));
  lien2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options[1]));
  lien3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(options[2]));

  liste1.appendChild(lien1);
  liste2.appendChild(lien2);
  liste3.appendChild(lien3);

  listeSansOrdre.appendChild(liste1);
  listeSansOrdre.appendChild(liste2);
  listeSansOrdre.appendChild(liste3);

  navigateur.appendChild(listeSansOrdre);
  document.body.appendChild(navigateur);

  //La partie section et article de la page 
  var section = document.createElement("Section");
  var article = document.createElement("Article");
  var paraArticle = document.createElement("p");
  var lien = document.createElement("a");
  var nomLien = document.createTextNode("wikipedia");
  var articleNode = document.createTextNode("JavaScript est un langage de programmation de scripts principalement employe dans les pages web interactives mais aussi pour les serveurs avec l'utilisation (par exemple) de Node.JS.");

  paraArticle.appendChild(articleNode);

  lien.href = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript";

  paraArticle.appendChild(articleNode);

  lien.appendChild(nomLien);

  // La balise article qui prend les informations
  article.appendChild(paraArticle);
  article.appendChild(lien);

  section.appendChild(article);
  document.body.appendChild(section);

  //Le footer de la page 
  var footer = document.createElement("footer");
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var nom = document.createTextNode(" Kevin Louis ");
  para.appendChild(nom);
  footer.appendChild(para);
  document.body.appendChild(footer);


  //CSS en JavaScript

  //Style pour le body
  document.body.style.width = "100%";
  document.body.style.heigth = "100%";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
  document.body.style.fontSize = "1em";

  //Style pour le header
  header.style.width = "100%";
  header.style.height = "20%";
  header.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  header.style.fontSize = "1.5em";

  //Style pour le footer
  footer.style.width = "100%";
  footer.style.height = "20%";
  footer.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  footer.style.fontSize = "1.5em";
  footer.style.fontStyle = "italic";

  //Style pour le nav 
  navigateur.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
  navigateur.style.border = "thick double black";
  navigateur.style.width = "20%";


  //Style pour la section
  section.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
  section.style.border = "thick double black";
  section.style.width = "70%";
  section.style.height = "45%";

}

function animerImage() {
  var logo = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  logo[0].style.transition = "height 2s";
  logo[0].style.WebkitTransition = "height 2s";

}
```

```css
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0%;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
}

img {
  transition: width 2s;
}

img:hover {
  width: 27%;
  /*height: 17%;*/
}

@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
  section {
    width: 100% !important;
    left: 0%;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  footer {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media all and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("../Images/arriereplan.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TP1 - DÉPART - Créer dynamiquement une page web adaptive en HTML5</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="genererpage()">Génére la page</button>
  <button onclick="animerImage()">Change l'animation</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascripts/fonctions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `transition` is set at `click` of button, though  `height` of element is not changed after `click`. What is expected result?

Comment: Height of the logo increase by 50% with a 2s height transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to improve guest271314 answer but as he mentioned, and I'm guessing his right, I'm giving my own answer.

So I'm guessing what you're trying to achieve is on mouseover the image will do a stretch animation on the with for 2s and then once thats done it will run another animation for 2s on the height.

Is that correct?

```html
<img id="cats" src="http://lorempixel.com/175/110/cats" width="175" height="110" />

<script>
  function animerImage() {
    var logo = document.getElementById("cats");
    logo.style.width = (logo.width * 1.5) + "px";
    logo.style.height = (logo.height * 1.5) + "px";
  }

  document.querySelector("#cats").onmouseover = animerImage;
</script>

<style>
   #cats {
      -webkit-transition: width 2, height 2s linear 2s;
      transition: width 2s, height 2s linear 2s;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`transition` is set, though `height` is not changed. You can set `height` to current `.height` divided by `2` added to current `.height` within `animerImage()` call.

```html
<button>click</button>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/175/110/cats" width="175" height="110"/>
<script>


function animerImage() {
  var logo = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  logo[0].style.transition = "height 2s";
  logo[0].style.WebkitTransition = "height 2s";
  var height = logo[0].height / 2;
  logo[0].style.height = logo[0].height + height + "px";
}

document.querySelector("button").onclick = animerImage;
</script>
```

Comment: I was expecting being able to increase the height by 50% + add a 2s transition while hovering the logo

Comment: @Kevin The `height` is increased by 50% of the original `height`. Do you mean 100%? Where is hover described at Question? Is `click` event intended to only set the `transition`? Do you mean `css` `:hover` or `mouseover` event? What is purpose of `click` event at `button`? You can use `css` `:hover` to set  `height` property.

Comment: Sorry didn't mention it in the question but yeah It should the transition should go from 2s width to 2s height while increasing the height by 50%, with the :hover

Comment: @Kevin _"It should the transition should go from 2s width to 2s height while increasing the height by 50%, with the :hover"_  Do you mean in sequence? How is `click` on `button` related to the above described expected result? Or is requirement to use only `css` `:hover` pseudo class?

Comment: updated the example from @Kevin for a more clear understanding - http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15451521

Comment: updated the example from guest271314 with the usage of mouseover and 2s of animation for with and height, I believe thats what you're trying to achieve @Kevin - http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15451549